# DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString() fails with NullPointerException on Android 5

Tags: android, datetime, kotlin

I am encountering a rather strange issue when trying to use `DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(...)` with some particular values.

I am using it like this:

```
private fun formatPubDate(pubDate: String): String {
   val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.ENGLISH)
   val date = dateFormat.parse(pubDate)
   val flags = DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE or DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME or DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR or DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_MONTH

   return DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(date.time, System.currentTimeMillis(),
                DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS, flags).toString()
}
```

Why is it strange? Because the following code works as expected, printing to console "*6 days ago*":

```
Log.d("DATE_TAG", formatPubDate("Fri, 09 Jul 2018 07:04:05 +0000"))
```

However, if the date is changed from 09 Jul to 08 July:

```
Log.d("DATE_TAG", formatPubDate("Fri, 08 Jul 2018 07:04:05 +0000"))
```

then the app crashes with the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference
        at android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(DateFormat.java:131)
        at android.text.format.DateUtils.formatDateRange(DateUtils.java:822)
        at android.text.format.DateUtils.formatDateRange(DateUtils.java:650)
        at android.text.format.DateUtils.formatDateRange(DateUtils.java:627)
        at android.text.format.DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(DateUtils.java:350)
        at test.com.recyclerviewwidth.MainActivity.formatPubDate(MainActivity.kt:26)
        at test.com.recyclerviewwidth.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:18)
```

**So far the issue was reproducible only on Android 5**, on a Samsung device and on an Emulator (on Android 8 and 7 works fine).

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the FORMAT_SHOW_TIME flag : I had the same pb here and fixed it *in a kinda dirty way* by catching the exception and calling again the DateUtil method **without the FORMAT_SHOW_TIME flag**.